# How to get rid of a comma while writing a CV?

Tags: awesome-cv

I am working on Awesome CV (downloaded from here https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm). Nevertheless, I can't get rid of the comma that stands after "B.S. in Computer Science and Engineering". Here is the output: [image] :

And there is the full code :

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{cvitems*}[1][2]
 {\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \begin{multicols}{#1}
  \begin{cvitems}}
 {\end{cvitems}%
  \end{multicols}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{2mm}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Some}{Name}
\address{An Address, 3245}
\mobile{(+57) 45-45654-434} 
%%% Social
\email{somethingHere@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.SomePage.com}
\github{Someone2}
\linkedin{Someone2}
%%% Optionals
\position{My Position}
\quote{``I am me.''}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {My Resume}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

\cvsection{Formation}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SUBSECTION TITLE
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\cvsubsection{International}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTENT
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{cvhonors}

%---------------------------------------------------------
    \cvhonor
    { B.S. in Computer Science and Engineering} % Award
    {} % Event
    {Seoul} % Location
    {2022-2023} % Date(s)


%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cvhonor
    {B.S in Computer Science and Engineering} % Award
    {} % Event
    {Seoul} % Location
    {2019-2022} % Date(s)




%---------------------------------------------------------
\end{cvhonors}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\cvhonor` has a pretty simple definition in the document class file. It looks like this:

```
\newcommand*{\cvhonor}[4]{%
  \honordatestyle{#4} & \honorpositionstyle{#1}, \honortitlestyle{#2} & \honorlocationstyle{#3} \\
}
```

You could redefine it by putting this at the end of your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\cvhonor}[4]{%
  \honordatestyle{#4} & \honorpositionstyle{#1} \honortitlestyle{#2} & \honorlocationstyle{#3} \\
}
```

(Just taking out that comma.)

If you do want a comma in some instances of course you'd then have to add it manually.